# Spring security jwt unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

New to unit testing, how would I go about testing this class in

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class JwtAuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    @Autowired
    private JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(token));
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            throw new Exception("USER_DISABLED", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new Exception("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", e);
        }enter code here
    }
}
```

here is the rest of the code:

https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot-jwt

Answer (score 0):

You can test in a couple of ways. Unit and Integration. Unit testing would require mocking all the dependencies and Integration(some call it Unit) will require simply testing the web layer. Since you are using Spring I would suggest you have a look at this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)